# Какие библиотеки бы мне посоветовали использовать для чтения файлов bmp, jpg , на СИ

Tags: c, поиск-библиотек, распознавание

Меня зовут Тимур.
Я не программист. Я наладчик станков с чпу. Но мне захотелось научиться программировать. Я выучил и понял принципы языка Си (не зная еще в полной мере оптимальных алгоритмов решения некоторых стандартных задач, но это не так важно на данном этапе для меня).

Моя жена учитель музыки и иногда приходится делать транспонирование музыки в другую тональность.
Чтобы это сделать, музыка должна быть в цифровом виде (например, midi файл), тогда программа, что работает с цифровыми нотами (например, Sibelius) сможеть поднять или опустить на тон или полтона, и сама поменяет нотные знаки и распечатает.
Однако, это все работает с уже оцифрованными нотами (причем, понятие оцифорованные ноты означает, что ноты в специальном формате, и это НЕ pdf и не файл фото и не doc! Это может быть, например, midi. (на самом деле Midi файл содержит не ноты, указания на нажатия тех или иных клавиш на том или ином виртуальном инструменте, но это может легко интерпретироваться как и ноты).

Ну так вот, чтобы это все хорошо работало, нужна программа, что из pdf или jpg или bmp распознает ноты и делает midi файл. (или совместимый с ним).

Это как FineReader для нот на бумаге. На самом деле такие программы есть, но они все платные и мне это не нравится.

Например, мы не можем их использовать в школе.

Я хочу написать свою программу, что будет брать файл картинки и выдавать файл midi.

Я более менее знаю Си и только начал изучать С++, но я склоняюсь, что буду писать на Си, так как хочу, чтобы программа была кроссплатформенной.

Подскажите пожалуйста, какие библиотеки Вы бы мне посоветовали использовать для чтения файлов bmp, jpg , pdf?

Также я хочу прояснить вот что. Я хочу написать программу без графического интерфейса (так как еще не умею это делать), и моя задумка в том,
чтобы сделать сам движок-распознаватель нот, работающий в консоли, а в будещем возможно другие люди напишут GUI часть к нему. (Как например, в Linux есть программа parted, и также Gparted - последняя является GUI к консольной основной программе).
Правильно ли я так решил делать?

Еще подскажите, какие могут быть использованы методы вывода из моей программы: в файл или разделяемую память или может  есть что то еще, чего я не знаю??) Вывод в файл мне кажется это самое простое и удобное для конечного пользователя.

И еще - подскажите, вы имели дело с похожей задачей? Какой здесь можно использовать алгоритм?

P.S. Объясню причины выбора именно языка СИ. Я изначально хотел RUST или D, но так получилось, что они не работают на моем старом macbook 2009 года, а вот Си без проблем пошел, я сделал пробную программу, скомпилировал под macos (причем как в GCC, так и в Clang) с флагом -DUNIX, все успешно скомпилировалось (я попробовал библиотеку 4th - реализация Forth на СИ), программа без проблем пошла как в Macos, так и в Linux и в Windows и даже на PowerPC.
Связи с чем, я еще больше уверовал в мощь и кросплатформенность языка Си и в то, что правильно написанный код на Си будет работать практически на любой машине. Вы можете заметить что есть еще и Java, но я не дружу с ООП (я только начал это изучать), ну и я на самом деле экспериментировал в том числе и с Java, и могу сказать, что столкнулся с ситуацией, когда я скомпилииовал Java программу в файл Class, он у меня пошел на Windows, но не пошел на PowerPc, хотя там тоже стояла Java, но более старой версии. А вот с Си проблем не было никаких.

С уважением, Тимур

Comment: Вот список нужного вам ПО, в том числе и свободного https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_music_recognition

Comment: буду писать на Си, так как хочу, чтобы программа была кроссплатформенной. - с каких пор c++ плафтофмернно зависимее сильнее чем Си?